# How to add faded borders to the inside of a grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a website in Bootstrap 4 based from a design. There is one element I can't think of how to approach this in CSS.

I can do the grid and content easily. The issue is putting the fade effect on each of the borders

[image: Image of bootstrap 4 grid]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12 mb-5 px-2 px-md-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It has 3+ months MOT </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It is not an import </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">       
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It is not an insurance write off </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It has never been used for private/commercial hire, rental, driving tuition </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It has no serious mechanical issues </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> You have the V5 in your name </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0"> It has full service history </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 px-4">
            <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NMnvaTiNRxi61-XRT5ss_g.png" class="img-fluid p-3 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Icon of the AMT tick in a circle">
            <h5 class="red pr-0">It has no more than 50,000 miles</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```